# Video compression using light compressor takes a lot of time in Android

Tags: android, android-mediacodec, android-ffmpeg

In my app, I have video recording functionality. Using a phone camera we can record around 1o mins video. As the 10 min video size is more, we want to compress it first and then upload it to Amazon S3.

Now for the whole process, we used [LightCompressor] (https://github.com/AbedElazizShe/LightCompressor), and using this we can compress the video size to 5 mins video. But it is taking too much time to compress, almost 4-5 mins. Even different phones are taking more time.

As per my understanding, it uses MediaCodec for this purpose. I have a few questions in these regards:

1. What is the best way to compress these large videos?
2. Are there any other library that is more efficient?
3. is FFmpeg can help here?

Can someone help?

Answer (score 0):

Operating on an already encoded video file is *demanding*. You must either supply a decoded video stream first to the encoder, or the encoder must operate directly on the file using a way more complex set of computations. (Hell, I don't even know whether that kind of operation is possible.) Desktop systems or even dedicated servers suffer from overheads when transcoding already existing files.

Therefore, if you have to deal with future recordings, it is generally not a good idea to record first and transcode. Instead, I would like to suggest you that you target a lower bitrate (which must be satisfied to upload to your Amazon instance, presumably) from the beginning.

On a side note, since the file size is proportional to *the bitrate* multiplied by *the duration*, you can effectively reduce the file size not only by shrinking its duration, but also by lowering the quality. If quality could be sacrificed, consider reducing the final bitrate.

Regarding the original sub-questions,

1. Not to deal with "large videos" in the beginning. Instead, we lower our expected bitrate in the beginning if the video's only use case requires a much lower bitrate.
2. Not significantly. `MediaCodec` already deals with the specialized media processor to hardware-accelerate the transcoding, so unless there is a serious flaw in the library you are using, any other methods would not be remarkably promising.
3. `ffmpeg` can either operate in the software mode (`x264`) or in the hardware mode (`MediaCodec`). However, I don't expect `x264` to be significantly faster than the already verified `MediaCodec` library.